# How to parse drive from path with windows naming convention?

Tags: php, windows, file, parsing

PHP has many good functions like [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php), [basename](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php), [dirname](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.dirname.php) and so on. And many question on stackoverflow about path parts. But most of them do not support windows file paths convention -[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Look at this correct path:

```
\\?\UNC\server\share\file.txt
  ----   ----------   ------
    |        |          |-> File 
    |        |-> Path
    |-> Driver
```

The "drive" could be:

- "\\.\"
- "\\.\PhysicalDiskX" (where X is a valid integer value)
- "\??\" (kernel level file resolving)
- "Global??" and so on

And some aspects with short/long naming conventions.

### Question

How to parse file path obey to windows naming convention?